# How to read a text file and split the lines where there is a full stop

Tags: python, string, list

I want to read in a text file and split the lines where there is a full stop and also where there is a line break (\n) and create a list of strings where each string is a sentence from the file.
I have this code:

```
source_file = "textfile.txt" # "The cat jumped over the dog\n. The dog ran. etc."

def load_text_file(source_file):
    res = []
    with open(source_file, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
        txt = f.read()
        for line in f:
            res.append(line)
    return res 

list_res = load_text_file(source_file)
print(list_res)
```

Desired output list_res = ["The cat jumped over the dog.", " ", "The dog ran.", " ", "etc."]

Comment: After `f.read()`, `f` is exhausted. Get rid of `txt = f.read()`. Further, you can simply write `return list(f)` instead of writing an explicit loop.

Answer (score 0):

This makes a list like you want, by line, without \n:

```
source_file = "textfile.txt" # "The cat jumped over the dog\n. The dog ran. etc."

list_res = open(source_file, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore', mode='r').read().splitlines()
```

Output:

> ['The cat jumped over the dog.', '', 'The dog ran.', '', 'etc.']